# "Функция" в теле программы. Как сделать?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно создать функцию, но только в теле программы, в main'е. Но не могу, выдается как правило ошибка. Как по другому я могу сделать такое? Чтобы в начале мейна создать его, а потом в серединах программы вызвать его как функцию, одной строкой?

Comment: Покажите, что у вас на данный момент уже имеется, и вам подскажут, как исправить.

Comment: Причем тут что имеется? Я не о всей программе спрашиваю, а о конкретном случае! У меня в мейне имеются переменные к которым согласно выбору пользователя присваивается какое то значение и дальше идет согласно этому выбору. Но когда я пишу функцию до мейна, то она как раз таки не видит то что творится в мейне. Вот я и спрашиваю, как можно написать подобное функции не ДО мейна, а внутри мейна? @RomanoO

Comment: @navi, может быть, стоит передавать выбранные пользователем значения в качестве аргументов этой функции?   
Как таковых замыканий (анонимных функций/«функций в теле программы») нет. Приведите кусок программы, отображающий основную её логику — зачем вам нужно именно замыкание?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, без "извращений" такое сделать нельзя. А зачем обязательно объявлять внутри main(), почему нельзя вынести за её пределы?

Comment: @delphist007 потому что он не узнает эти переменные если она стоит до мейна, т.к значения этих переменных определяются по ходу мейновой части и пользователь сам их вводит

Comment: @navi, повторюсь:  
> может быть, стоит передавать выбранные пользователем значения в качестве аргументов этой функции?

Comment: @delphist007 @VioLet подскажете как мне сделать? Ну т.е передавать их в виде аргументов? Буду очень благодарен за такую помощь

Comment: @navi  

 #include <stdio.h>
 int foo(int a);

 int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
 {
  int value = 0;
  printf("Value: ");
  scanf("%d", &value);
  printf("The foo(%d) is %d", value, foo(value));
  return 0;
 }

 int foo(int a)
 {
  return (a*a + 52*91);
 }
  
Это Си, для C++ всё то же.

Answer (score 12):

C++ не поддерживает nested functions.
В С можно сделать например так:

```
//  Example 3
//
int f( int i )
{
  int j = i*2;
  int g( int k )
  {
    return j+k;
  }
  j += 4;
  return g( 3 );
}
```

Правда в С++ внутри тела функции можно поместить объявление класса, внутри которого поместить объявление соответствующей функции(с помощью перегрузки оператора ()) и получить таким образом функтор(объект-функцию), но это не будет работать так как внутри этого класса не будет видно членов main.

```
 //  Example 3(a): Naive "local functor"
  //                approach (doesn't work)
  //
  int f( int i )
  {
    int j = i*2;
    class g_
    {
    public:
      int operator()( int k )
      {
        return j+k;   // error: j isn't accessible
      }
    } g;
    j += 4;
    return g( 3 );
  }
```

[Вот ссылка](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/058.htm) в которой рассмотрены различные трюки эмулирования поведения nested function через local class.

Еще добавлю что наверняка можно сделать еще проще и просто написать ваш код по первому варианту внутри директивы:

```
 extern "C"{}
```

Comment: О, спасибо. Не знал, что С поддерживает встроенные функции.

Comment: @igumnov, спасибо, тоже не знал про внутренние функции. 

Когда они появились?

Думал, что кроме \#define тут (в смысле вопроса @navi1893) ничего не придумать.

Comment: @avp В gnu extensions -- давно. :)

Comment: @avp Когда появились понятия не имею, так как не работаю с gcc. Вот пару ссылок.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=653636
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function

Answer (score 6):

К ответу [[@igumnov](/users/7053/igumnov)](/users/7053/igumnov) добавлю, что можно использовать лямбда-функции из [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/lambda.html) или из С++11, если есть возможность его использовать.

**Added.** Вот еще встретил в Boost библиотеку [local_function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/local_function/doc/html/index.html)

***Added***Вот еще придумал.

```
void func () {
  struct nested {
    static void nf () {
      //do something
    }
  };

  nested::nf ();
}
```

Чтобы избавиться от имени класса при вызове, можно получить указатель на функцию-член и с ним работать

```
void (*nested_func) () = &nested::nf;
nested_func();
```

Comment: @mikillskegg, функция внутри структуры это только в С++? И зачем ей static ?

Comment: Это только в С++. В С можно поместить указатель на какую-то функцию. А static - чтобы можно было ее вызывать без создания экземпляра класса. Тут класс или структура просто выполняет роль обертки, позволяющей поместить функцию внутрь другой функции.

Comment: Только это не функция, а этот, как его, член класса. Такой вот получается член

Comment: @alexlz, это не просто член, это член-функция

Comment: @mikillskegg а что такое функторы? В prolog'е и теории категорий/`*ml*`/haskell это сильно разные понятия.

Comment: В С++ так называются объекты, которые можно вызывать как функции. По сути это объекты классов с перегруженным оператором ().

Comment: @mikillskegg спасибо, не знал.

Comment: Попробовал чуть-чуть. 

Не понимаю, что (кроме доступа к глобальным переменным) можно делать из static nf().

Если static убрать, то появляется (кроме глобальных) доступ к полям экземпляра структуры. Тут понятно, как можно использовать, а со static нет.

Кстати, у меня с emb:: вообще ничего не компилится, видимо что-то кардинально не понимаю.

--

В Си с указателем на функцию - это понятно. Сейчас поиграюсь со встороенными функциями в Си и указателями на них (интересно,   к каким нелокальным переменным в рекурсии будет доступ).

Comment: @avp nested:: или поменять имя класса/структуры на emb

Comment: Ну да, к локальным переменным доступа не будет.

Comment: Интересная картина с вложенными функциями в Си и рекурсией. 

    void f(void (*fu)()) { fu(); }
      ...
    void f1(int l) {
      ...
      void f2() {  ... }
      if (l)
        f1(l-1);
      f(f2);
    }
      
Т.е. f2() вложена в рекурсивную f1(), которая вызывает f() и передает ей f2().

На каждом уровне рекурсии f2() видит (как и ожидалось) соответствующие этому уровню переменные в f1(). 

Самое интересное, что адрес у f2 на каждом уровне **новый**. Т.о. если запоминать эти адреса (во внешнем для f1() массиве), то можно получить **доступ к переменным в f1() более ранних уровней!!!*

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1:

```
int main()
{
    struct{void operator()(int a)
    {
        cout << a;
    }} print;

    print(123);
}
```

Вариант 2 (C++11):

```
int main()
{
    int a=123;
    auto printA=[&]()
    {
        cout << a;
    };

    printA();
}
```

Вариант 3: А почему бы просто не создать класс с нужными полями и методами и не пихать всё в main?

Comment: По сути это уже было: функторы и лямбда-функции. Но детали интересные.

Comment: Лямбда = анонимный функтор

Comment: Нет, лямбда, в отличие от функторов не может хранить внутри себя своё состояние. Захватываемые по значению переменные становятся константами.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о чем идет речь, что мешает использовать захват по ссылке [&] вместо захвата по значению. Тогда перегрузка const () будет действовать на ссылку, а не на сам объект.

Comment: Тогда состояние будет храниться в функторе, а во внешней переменной. Инкапсуляции никакой не будет.