# Сокрытие функции

Tags: c++

Есть функция

```
double funct(double);
```

Она содержит вызов некоторых других функций. Но они должны быть скрыты всему, кроме этой "главной" функции.
Как?

Comment: А кто им мешает быть скрытыми "по договоренности"?

Но раз такая необходимость возникла, может сделать эту функцию методом класса? а необходимые скрытые - приватными.

Comment: Т.е. достаточно создать им namespace, и прокомментировать, что функции использовать не следует.
Класс - это все-таки некоторые данные.

Comment: Сделайте класс `StaticHelperClass`, в котором будут содержаться только статические функции, объявите в нем `static double funct(double);` как публичную, а вспомогательные статические функции сделайте приватными.

Comment: А что значит всему? Вы сами не должны ничего видеть в редакторе? Или что. Если функции не должны быть видны вне данной единицы трансляции, то есть описатель static

Comment: @hungry_tomcat а класс-то зачем?

Comment: Я решил проблему так: в файле funct.h объявление функции, в funct.cpp определение всех вспомогательных функций и ее самой. Нормально ли так поступать?

Comment: >Я решил проблему так: в файле funct.h объявление функции, в funct.cpp определение всех вспомогательных функций и ее самой. Нормально ли так поступать?

Если целью было скрыть вспомогательные функции из заголовочного файла, то вполне нормальное решение. Хотя Ваш ответ меня все же немного разочаровал, не об этом я думал, когда читал вопрос :)

Comment: @iofjuupasli Вам решать, правильно или нет. Если функции не статические, то они видны линковщику.

@mega Да, такое решение не сильно приближает разработчика к вершинам мастерства (см. "Эволюцию программиста")

Comment: Получается, что проблема в том, что если я попытаюсь объявить функцию где-то еще, то линковщик таки найдет ее в том самом cpp файле. Да, получается, что это не совсем то, про что я спросил, но то, что мне надо было.

Comment: Линковщик не может найти функцию в cpp файле. Он такого не ест. Он работает с объектными модулями (результаты трансляции) и библиотеками (объединения объектных модулей)

В реальности картинка несколько сложнее, но сейчас это не важно

Comment: @iofjuupasli, Вы для начала ответьте **зачем вообще эта паранойя Вам нужна?**. 

Какую степень "невызываемости" Вы хотите обеспечить? Например, если в загрузочном модуле есть таблица символов, то любую (в т.ч. статическую) функцию можно вызвать, например, используя приемы, применяемые отладчиком.

Реально же (в большом проекте) надо просто стремиться избежать случайного пересечения по именам с другими разработчиками (в т.ч. сторонних библиотек).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд, здесь подходит стандартное решение. Оно заключается в том, что создаются два файла:

**my.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
....
// столько инклюдов, сколько нужно

// сделать guardian для единичного включения include-файла!!!
// стандартно - через define-ifdef или pragma

double funct(double); // прототип нашей ф-ции
// не уверен, но возможно понадобится запись extern
// для включения my.h в проект потребителя
```

**my.cpp**

```
#include <my.h>
....
// код всех вспомогательных ф-ций

double funct (double) {...}    // код нашей ф-ции
```

Если замучала паранойя - все вспомогательные ф-ции можно сделать **static**, т.е. они будут доступны только из **my.cpp**. Еще вариант - не распространять потребителям файл my.cpp, а предоставлять им объектный модуль (obj-файл) или библиотеку (lib-файл).

Еще более хитрый метод - собрать динамическую библиотеку с ф-цией funct, чтобы она была в таблице экспорта... Тогда "кишки" библиотеки будут недоступны снаружи (по крайней мере без хитростей). Это возможно хорошо, если нужно реализовать концепцию черного ящика. Но вот нужно ли так изворачиваться - вопрос.

***Интересной методикой ограничения доступа из других модулей является использование безымянного пространства имен. [Например](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/2039516.flat) или [так](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yct4x9k5.aspx)***

Вообще было бы неплохо, если автор вопроса все-таки рассказал, зачем ему нужно такое скрытие...

Comment: Я уже вышел указывал это решение, а также то, что вопрос был поставлен некорректно. (зато все поизвращались и отшутились)

Answer (score 3):

Можно так, довольно дешево:

```
class MyPublic{
  void funct( ... ){
    return static_cast< MyPrivate* >( this )->priv_funct( ... );
  }
};
```

В каком-то богом забытом `namespace` (о котором `MyPublic` не должен забывать), или прямо в `funct'е`, если код не будет слишком громоздким:

```
class MyPrivate : public MyPublic{
  void something_hidden( ... ){
    ...
  }
  void priv_funct( ... ){
    return something_hidden( ... );
  }
};
```

Только `MyPrivate` не должен добавлять ни каких данных предку, иначе, это придется учитывать. Можно поиграться еще с модификатором доступа наследования, но если целью было - избавиться от вспомогательных методов в инструментах, по типу `IntelliSense`, то этого будет достаточно.

Comment: Некруто, что в таком случае базовый класс начинает что-то знать о своих `derived` классах.

Comment: Только о тех, кто реализует его функционал. Не уверен, что их можно называть полноценными потомками, не имеют они своего тела, это фантомы :)

Comment: Может, лучше dynamic_cast использовать?

Comment: >Может, лучше dynamic_cast использовать?

`dynamic_cast` - это поиск среди физически-сформированных вершин классов, которые связаны с `vmt`. Т.е. это поиск в реальном объекте, а здесь - "фантом". Он будет найден только в случае, если объект `MyPrivate` реально создан. Да и больно уж дорогой это метод - он явно не лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать как встроенную функцию (по мотивам [обсуждения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153293/c-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1))

```
void func () {
  struct hider {
    static void hidden_function() {
      //something
    }
  };

  void (*hf) () = &hider::hidden_function;
  hf();

}
```

Comment: А еще ее адрес можно зашифровать и  хранить на сервере, получая оттуда по предъявлению секретного пароля непосредственно перед вызовом функции, а после вызова локальную копию сразу затирать.

Пользователи уже встали в очередь за новыми мультиядерными гигагерцами и гигабайтами.

Comment: Шутка хороша.

Comment: >а после вызова локальную копию сразу затирать

Ни в коем случае, локальная копия - прошлый век. Сейчас уже саму функцию хранят на сервере, которому по предъявлению секретного пароля передаются только параметры. Сервер вызывает функцию и возвращает результат. [вспомнился "Hello World" @alexlz] :))

Comment: @mega ну как раз RPC -- они из прошлого века. И даже из прошлого тысячелетия. И даже до COM-технологий от MS (которые как раз RPC и используют)

Comment: >как раз RPC -- они из прошлого века

Точно! Забыл! В этом тысячелетии мы развернем хемидой виртуальную машину с динамически-меняющимся машинным псевдо-языком и передадим параметры в нее, а лучше - вложим таких машин штук 10.